# Asp.net MVC 4 admin Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm a kind of newbie with routing, I want to give the possibility to my user to go to the admin part of the site by just entering `www.hisSite.com/admin` whith a route that will redirect to the `SiteAdmin` controller and `Index` action. Is it possible?
I probably didn' understand something but I'm baddly stuck....

Comment: Why didnt you just rename your `SiteAdminController` to `AdminController`?

Comment: I thank you all to  help me to eventually understand the routes. Sure, I should have to rename my controller et the end of the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options that you can choose such as redirecting or creating a separate Area for the admin side however I think since you're a newbie just create a controller called `AdminController` and include an action called `Index` like below:

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    public Action Index()
    {
        // Some action
    }
}
```

To call this you'd only need to enter:

```
www.hisSite.com/admin
```

or

```
www.hisSite.com/admin/index
```

What's happening here is by using a convention of adding `Controller` suffix to each controller class, routing will recognise the first part i.e. `Admin` as a route when requested by a browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Admin",
                url: "admin/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "SiteAdmin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

This will route all urls pointing to www.hisSite.com/admin to actions and views in the SiteAdmin controller.

A simpler way is to just create a Admin controller ofcourse.

Comment: having a controller may be a simpler way, but isnt it a faster way to have a MapRoute? plz correct me if i am wrong..

Comment: its about the same. The only difference is that the routing table will have two routes rather than one. If you use the `AdminController` it will just use the default route from the routing tables. In case you want to have another controller that is named differently, You would have to rely on MapRoute to wire that connection.